# Have grey underneath last cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

Right now I'm using the good ol' `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`, but that leaves the bottom of the screen white. Is there a way to make it grey underneath the last cell? Like when you use static cells instead of dynamic, you get grey undernearth your last cell. Like maybe something that sets the unused cells to clear? Or have all cells initially clear and only set to white as they get filled in with data? All of the answers I find are always to use `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`, which leads to a result different than what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size and color of the `UView` to be of any size of color by using `let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))` and `footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.ANYCOLORYOUWANT`. And then after you have made a set the color for the `UIView`, you assign it as the `tableFooterView`. (width and height are anything you want). Like so:

```
let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let height: CGFloat = 20
let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

You can put the above code in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller with the `UITableView` (or subclass). The code produces a 20px high, full width, light gray view at the bottom of the `UITableView`.

If you have any questions please ask! :D

Comment: It doesn't change the area below the table view, it just adds an extra view. If you scroll 20pt more (the height of the added view), you will still see the "unwanted" background.

Answer (score 0):

There are no unused cells, you are seeing the `backgroundView`.

You could try:

```
 tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

I think you could also set the backgroundView to a custom view.